# Non-US citizen traveling to Australia on an expired US work visa, but valid Australian visitor visa from US?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, australia, tourist-visas, visa-extensions

I am Indian working in the USA and my visa extension was filed and currently in-process with US consulate. My US work visa expired a week ago. I have yet to get my status on it. I am planning to travel to Australia to visit my friend, and then travel to India after one week. I am holding a valid Australian visitor visa.

Does the visa status from the country of departure matter here?

Comment: Do you have advance parole from the US?

Comment: I assume you have checked into the implications for your US status of travel while your extension is being processed.

Comment: Many types of visa applications in the US are automatically considered 'abandoned' when you leave the country. Make sure you check this.

Comment: Note that US visas are solely for entry, and there is no such thing as a "visa extension". You can only apply for a new visa outside the US. A visa's expiration date has no relevance to your stay in the US; the visa's expiration date is just the last date you can *enter*. You can be admitted for months or years after the visa's expiration. What matters for your stay in the US is your *status*, as given on your I-94.

Comment: Thanks. Am going India to get stamping again so that i can return to US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, if you are not planning to return to the US on the same trip, neither Australia nor your airline(s) will care about the status of your US visa.

Comment: @Monie corleone While they won't care on the same trip, you must address the issues raised in the four comments above to make sure that you can re-enter the US (if you wish to do so) on a subsequent trip.